# Swagger to display different input on the action method

Tags: c#, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have ASP.NET Core 7 project with Swashbuckle. I have the following code:

```
// MyTestClass.cs
/// <summary>
/// My Test class
/// </summary>
/// <param name="MyProperty">My property</param>
public record MyTestClass(int MyProperty);
```

```
// MyController.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers;

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPut(Name = "MyPut")]
    public IActionResult Put(string theInput)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

While my action method expects a string `theInput`, I want Swagger UI to show that I am expecting `MyTestClass` **as if** my code looks like this:

```
    [HttpPut(Name = "MyPut")]
    public IActionResult Put(MyTestClass myTestClass)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

How can I fake the input type in Swagger documentation and tell it to show the documentation of `MyTestClass` instead of `string`. The idea here is that I am creating a forgiving API, if the client doesn't put the right schema, I want to allow it and deal with this through a different route.

Comment: Sounds like an instance of [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why exactly do you want to do this?

Comment: @GuruStron I did specify in the last paragraph the reason, a forgiving api, was it unclear?

Comment: Sorry, missed that.